# Split dataframe into list's based on id's

Tags: r

Please note, I'm not a programmer by trade. I'm literature student. So please bear with me.

I would like to improve the existing working procedure. Certainly function `split` is one option (I'm not sure how however).

Basically, I'm trying to subdivide existing dataframe into list of sub samples so that the sequnce of id's is not splitted into second list.

Here is working example together with sample data:

```
 df <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),rep(3,3),rep(4,2),5,6,7,8,9,rep(10,5)),r1=rep(1,40),r2=rep(2,40))


x <- transform(df, rec=ave(df$id,df$id, FUN=seq_along))
x$cum <- cumsum(x$rec)
x$dif <- diff(c(0,x$cum),1)
x$lab <- ifelse(x$dif!=1,0,1)
x$seq <- seq_along(x$id)
x$subs <- x$lab*x$seq 

seqrow <- seq(1,nrow(x),3) # how many rows approx. per part
rw <- x$subs[x$subs %in% seqrow]

start_rw <- c(1,rw[2:length(rw)])
end_rw <- c(start_rw[2:length(start_rw)]-1,nrow(x))

df.lst <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(start_rw)){
     df.lst[[i]] <- x[(start_rw[i]:end_rw[i]), ]
}
```

In each list the id's should be also sorted increasingly and should be arranged according to id's.

Comment: not sure what you're saying. You want to split based on `subs` but you don't want to split up the observations with the same IDs after you have split by `subs`?

Comment: no just the sequnce. For example id=c(1,1,1,2,2), should be splitted into [[1]] id=1,1,1 and [[2]] id=2,2 and not for example [[1]] id=1,1 [[2]] id=1,2,2

Comment: I don't understand what you want either. How far does this get you: `split(df, df$id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through your code, I would summarize your procedure as:

1. Compute `seqrow`, which is row numbers where you would be willing to split the list
2. Split `df` only at the positions in `seqrow` where `df$id` is new (hasn't appeared above); this list of positions is called `start_rw` in your code.

You can use `duplicated` to determine if `df$id` has appeared above or not, which enables you to grab `start_rw` more easily:

```
seqrow <- seq(1,nrow(df),3)
(start_rw <- intersect(which(!duplicated(df$id)), seqrow))
# [1]  1  4 13 16
```

All that remains is to split `df` at these positions. You can use `diff` to compute the number of elements in each grouping:

```
(groups <- rep(seq(start_rw), times=diff(c(start_rw, nrow(df)+1))))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
df.lst2 <- split(df, groups)
```

This matches the output of your code:

```
all.equal(unname(df.lst2), lapply(df.lst, function(x) x[,1:3]))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is certainly more effective and cleaner as my poor attempt. Thank you.